# Is there a way to swap control and alt keys in Pharo3.0?

Tags: pharo

I was trying to get pharo3.0 to try develop with it. i was wondering what happened to the Settings swapControlAndAltKeys. Is there a way to achieve the goal without that settings?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, that setting was removed, along with the functionality. The reason is that is was a hack, and an ugly one.

If you need some functionality (like using certain ctrl keys instead alt, common for windows users), please report your need in the mailing list, so we can take care and add them before releasing.